# Execute multiple hadoop commands

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to write a batch file with multiple hadoop commands. But when I execute it from Hadoop Command Line, it executes only one command (first one) and ignores remaining commands. Can someone help me please to execute multiple commands as a batch file.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Do you mean you are writing a bat file in Windows?

Comment: For example
hadoop fs -mkdir hdfs://localhost/mydir
hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost

Here I have two commands that I want to execute through a bat file or any other mode.

Comment: Is there any error? I think you can put these two commands in a bat file and execute them. If you does not run the bat in the command line, you may miss the output of `fs -ls` command. Can you paste the output of running your bat?

Comment: the third comment is wrong. I have tested, mutiple lines of "hadoop fs ..." commands runs very very slow.

Comment: What is hadoop command line?

Answer (score 0):

execute each hadoop command in a new cmd instance, like this:

```
cmd /C "hadoop fs -mkdir hdfs://localhost/mydir"
cmd /C "hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost"
```